# Folder shared in Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets

Good Morning,
I read that there can only be 1 owner of a document in Google drive that is shared. Does that go for shared FOLDERS in Google drive also?
Thanks,
Shandra

Answer (score 0):

yes. the owner can be always only one account. you can either transfer ownership or set another person as editor (who can do everything just like you but he is not able to claim the ownership)

[image]